# Working flow of readv and writev. What are all the advantages of using readv and writev instead of using the read and write?

Tags: c, system-calls

I am just trying to use readv() to fetch some data from a file. But always junk characters are being printed. I tried to allocate space to the iovec.iov_base but no luck there. And I even had a notion of why use readv function instead of just stick to using the read function which is much more simpler and readable. I am perplexed now to know need of readv and writev functions.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<fcntl.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<errno.h>
    #include<sys/uio.h>
    #include<sys/types.h>
    #include<sys/stat.h>
    #define MAX 50000
    int main()
    {
        struct iovec data[2];
        int i=0,fd;
        for(i=0; i<3 ; i++ )  {
            data[i].iov_len=MAX;
            data[i].iov_base=(char*) malloc(MAX); //if this line is in comment, segmentation fault will occur. 
            /* data[i].iov_base=(char*) malloc(0); //This is also working ?*/
        }
        fd=open("/tmp/test",O_RDWR);
        if(fd==-1){
            printf("can't open the input file\n");
            return 1;
        }
        readv(fd,data,3);
        for(i=0; i<2 ; i++ )  {
            printf("((%s))\n",(char*)data[i].iov_base);
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show your code instead of describing it.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: BTW did you Google "readv writev"

Comment: Yes Michael and I got only man pages in all those links and I will edit my question with my program. Also I got some programs from internet and It did the same.  I took a tour on stack overflow all of them were so specific to some situation. But I don't even know how it works correctly. I even check program in qnx but it even did the same as I did.

Comment: What do [`readv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readv.html) *return*?

Comment: Oh wait, it doesn't matter. You have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The array `data` only contain ***two*** elements, but you use ***three***. You should *still* check what `readv` returns, proper error checking is essential.

Comment: Some programmer dude though it contain only two elements it still works.

Comment: C have no bounds-checking. Going out of bounds of an array leads to UB, and makes all speculation of behavior pointless. And as you state in your question, it *doesn't* work, or you would not have posted your question.

Comment: Please read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).

Comment: The advantage is that can do the same amount of work using fewer system calls. System calls are expensive, comparable to 1000..10000 ticks. Transferring small amounts of data (a few hundred bytes) is relatively cheap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the POSIX [`readv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readv.html) and [`writev()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html) functions ('scatter read' and 'gather write' — see also Wikipedia on [Vectored I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectored_I/O)) when you're using file descriptors and need to group reads to or writes from a collection of different (non-contiguous) memory locations but you want the reading or writing to be done with a single function call.

For example, I have a program that needs to log some control data and a hex-dump of some binary data, but it would like to ensure that its writes are atomic.  So, I have a function like this:

```
static void log_message(int log_fd, const char *elapsed, const char *tag, const char *buffer, ssize_t nbytes)
{
    char hdrbuff[64];
    struct iovec vector[3];
    const char *data = format_image(buffer, nbytes);

    snprintf(hdrbuff, sizeof(hdrbuff), "%s %s %6ld\n", elapsed, tag, (long)nbytes);

    vector[0].iov_base = hdrbuff;
    vector[0].iov_len  = strlen(hdrbuff);
    vector[1].iov_base = CONST_CAST(char *, data);
    vector[1].iov_len  = strlen(data);
    vector[2].iov_base = "\n";
    vector[2].iov_len  = 1;
    if (writev(log_fd, vector, 3) <= 0)
        err_syserr("Failed to write log entry (%s: %ld)\n", tag, (long)nbytes);
}
```

It's a mild nuisance to need to write the newline, but the `format_image()` function can't add a stray newline. (It is a library function used elsewhere, and those other uses would be broken if it added an extra newline.)  However, `writev()` allows me to write it all without changing the library functions, and maximizes the chance that there won't be any interleaving on the file.  (In context, there's a second process using the same log file and same open file description, but the protocol is half-duplex, so there's only a small chance of temporarl overlap.  However, using the scatter/gather I/O minimizes the chance of problems.)

I don't have an example of using `readv()` that I can remember, but you'd use it when you know that you have multiple fixed size blocks of data to read into non-contiguous memory locations.

Comment: As a minor nit, I/O for a single readv/writev syscall is "intended" to be atomic, but it's not guaranteed (except for writes to pipes/FIFO's). I'd guess most (all?) implementation are atomic for reasonable sizes (<= PIPE_BUF / page size?), though.

Comment: Fair comment — I've modified the spiel so it makes fewer (no?) claims about atomicity.